# Exit the application Click OnBackPressed

Tags: android

I use this code info my android application MainActivity Class, Show the dailog For Quit the app if i click on yes app run continue its cant be exit. sorry for bad english

```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Toast.makeText(appContext, "BAck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        alert.setTitle(string.app_name);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alert.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {

                             finish();
                    }



                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }
                });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Comment: Just to be clear to other users, this is an ANTI PATTERN and shouldn't be implemented at all. Why ? Check this article to understand why: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/exit-application-dialogs-are-evil-dont.html

Answer (score 1):

You can override on `onBackPressed` callback:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Really Exit?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

**Update**

From your comment I guess you are overriding `onBackPressed` in child activity, so in such cases you have to close the parent activity as well as the current.

To do so, you have to set a flag to determine if you want to close the activity or no:

```
public static String KEY_EXIT_ME = "yourApp.exit_me";

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Really Exit?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                exitApp();
            }
        }).create().show();
}

public void exitApp(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class); // which may be MainActivity
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_EXIT_ME, true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Then in the `ParentActivity` `onCreate` method:

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_EXIT_ME, false)){
    finish();
    return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
}
```

Comment: @MrSingh Did you get any exceptions? any unexpected results?

Comment: i use this code and its replaced with my above code its show message Are you sure you want to exit? if i click on yes hide the app but on backend app is still running.

Comment: Hello i tried your code its worked now but in backend radio service will not destroy i check in apps running setting my radio app actualy running on backened and show message **This service is run by its app. RadioService stop will be fail.**

Comment: this line show error if i use ** .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {**  show error on OnClickListner or public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)  this

Answer (score 0):

instead of `finish();`

call

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting just finish(), try putting MainActivity.this.finish()...

also, you should put the AlertDialog.Builder inside of a DialogFragment, it is much more better.

Comment: i replace finish(); into MainActivity.this.finish(); but its cant work :(